# Verb-subject agreement with "Which courses is everyone going for?" and "Which courses are everyone going for?"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I sometimes get confused whenever there are both singular and plural nouns in one sentence such as:

1. "Which courses is everyone going for this semester?"
2. "Which courses are everyone going for this semester?"

The first feels like the correct one to me, but I was still hesitating a bit. Is it because "everyone" is the subject, and "to go for" has to agree with that? What is the official grammatical term for "courses" here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first one is indeed correct.

Everyone is used as singular, as answered in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225/is-everyone-singular-or-plural).

Now, in these sentences, the words 'is'/'are' would correspond to 'everyone'(You could also understand the logic of the statement by saying 'Everyone is going for -- courses this semester'). Since 'everyone' is singular, the verb will also be singular. Hence first statement is correct.

The word 'courses' here is for the object.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to answer this tricky question is to alter it slightly by giving different examples.

Would we say: **Which cars is he selling?** or **Which cars are he selling?**.

And: **Which trees is she pruning?** and **Which trees are she pruning?**

The second examples clearly sound wrong. They are not idiomatic.

The same principle applies to your examples.

So the answer is: **Which courses is everyone going for?**

Comment: It's beyond "not idiomatic" - "not idiomatic" means "grammatically correct but traditionally not what people say", but this is in fact even grammatically incorrect, as User07's answer explained.